# How to identify keys added via NSUserDefaults without having source code

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to add arrays,dictionaries via NSUserdefaults.

The physical path is rootOfMyApplication/Library/Preferences/bundleidentifier.appName.plist where I can see data that I stored via NSUserDefaults while testing on simulator.

**Suppose I give simulator hash folder to a friend without source code, will it be possible for him to identify the keys that I  have used while storing in NSUserdefaults?**

There are other keys in the plist ,How can we differentiate between the ones that are stored via NSuserdefaults?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience looking at the NSUserDefaults plist file shows that keys that start with the following are from Apple:

- Apple...
- NS...
- Web...

As long as you avoid those prefixes you should be able to find all of the app keys.

I always try to use a specific prefix to my keys to be safe but you don't have to.